# MIPS .space directive

Tags: assembly, mips

how do I allocate an array in MIPS, of a size determined by the data in a register?
pseudocode:

```
li $t0,30
.data
input_array:
.space $t0*4
```

everything I find about the .space directive indicates that it only takes an immediate value n.

Comment: Yes. You need to ask your OS or operating environment for dynamic memory at runtime (that you forgot to mention).

Comment: Can't help you unless you **specify what OS or environment**.

Comment: The code will be run on an ubuntu machine

Comment: You have an actual MIPS-based computer that you're running Ubuntu on? If not, you should specify how you're _really_ going to run your MIPS code, such as in a simulator/emulator (which one?).

Answer (score 0):

In assembly program, you don't allocate anything, especially data structures. The data structures in assembly are how you use a block of memory. You can, of course, ask (allocate) more memory for your program from the OS (if you are not programming bare metal), but still it's just memory. The way you access it makes it an array.